# Creating List from initializer

Tags: c#, list, initializer

Is there any difference between

```
var list = new List<UserType>
{
    new UserType(...),
    new UserType(...),
};
```

and

```
var list = new List<UserType>()
{
    new UserType(...),
    new UserType(...),
};
```

?

I used to use always the second one thinking that I'm just required to call the list's parameterless (or any other) constructor...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: A tool like ReSharper will notify you that you can remove the `()` when using the initializer. Assuming you have no parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

> The object initializer syntax enables you to specify arguments for a
>   constructor or omit the arguments (and parentheses syntax)

The same rule applies to list and ordinary object initializers:

```
var foo = new Bar {
    Prop = "value"
};
```

Comment: You should note that this is just syntactic sugar as the compiler just translates it to .Add() calls:

"By using a collection initializer you do not have to specify multiple calls to the Add method of the class in your source code; the compiler adds the calls."

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no difference. The IL generated is *exactly* the same:

```
IL_0001:  newobj      System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+UserType>..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.1     // <>g__initLocal0
IL_0007:  ldloc.1     // <>g__initLocal0
IL_0008:  newobj      UserQuery+UserType..ctor
IL_000D:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+UserType>.Add
IL_0012:  nop         
IL_0013:  ldloc.1     // <>g__initLocal0
IL_0014:  newobj      UserQuery+UserType..ctor
IL_0019:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+UserType>.Add
IL_001E:  nop         
IL_001F:  ldloc.1     // <>g__initLocal0
IL_0020:  stloc.0     // list
```

Even instantiating a new `List` and calling `.Add` yourself is quite similar, i.e.:

```
var list = new List<UserType>();

list.Add(new UserType());
list.Add(new UserType());
```

... generates:

```
IL_0001:  newobj      System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+UserType>..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // list
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // list
IL_0008:  newobj      UserQuery+UserType..ctor
IL_000D:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+UserType>.Add
IL_0012:  nop         
IL_0013:  ldloc.0     // list
IL_0014:  newobj      UserQuery+UserType..ctor
IL_0019:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+UserType>.Add
```

Which is slightly different -- looks like the difference is generating a temporary variable and assigning it to `list` vs creating and manipulating `list` directly.